# SSRS Top N for Dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

So I am currently writing an SSRS report which I want to calculate lead time based on an arbitrary number deliveries.

I have my query in SSRS but now I would like to filter it to show the last 5 deliveries. Usually I would use a Top N for filtering but SSRS rightly complains that the number 5 is not a date.

How do you filter the last five latest dates without knowing the exact dates of the records you are returning?

Dataset is as follows (lead time is a calculation of order date less delivery date)

```
Order | Del_Date   | Lead_Time
------|------------|-----------
00001 | 2015-05-01 | 20
00002 | 2015-01-08 | 21
00003 | 2015-02-05 | 22
00004 | 2015-03-11 | 26
00005 | 2015-01-21 | 8
00006 | 2015-04-12 | 12
00007 | 2015-03-02 | 12
00008 | 2015-02-01 | 12
```

The query should return

```
Order | Del_Date   | Lead_Time
------|------------|-----------
00001 | 2015-05-01 | 20
00003 | 2015-02-05 | 22
00004 | 2015-03-11 | 26
00006 | 2015-04-12 | 12
00007 | 2015-03-02 | 12
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data set?

Comment: I've updated the post with an example dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT TOP 5
    Order,
    Del_Date,
    Lead_Time
FROM
    [TABLE]
...
ORDER BY
    Del_Date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the data set definition as Matteo suggested or apply a filter to the object displaying the data. Based on your question I am assuming you want to use the object displaying the data to filter your results.

To get the top 5 dates change the data object sorting to the date field and order "Z to A". Then under filters select the date field you want in the expression box. Set the operator to "Top N" and set the value to "=5".

Answer (score 0):

If tablix filter complains about top 5, then you can bring  row_number (ranking) to tablix and filter it by  ranking <=5